# Rails 5 - Saving the absolute current url via a button to a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to let users in my application be able to click a button that says "Save current page" and be able to access it later to take them back to that same page no matter what unless they save a different page.

I believe doing it through a cookie is the best way?

Here's what I've tried:

**homepage view:**

```
<%= link_to "Return to your last question", cookies[:saved_url], :class => "button is-info" %>
```

**controller:**

```
def resume
  cookies.permanent[:saved_url] = request.original_url
  redirect_to :saved_url
end
```

**view:**

```
<%= link_to 'Save Progress', users_resume_path, method: :post %>
```

**route:**

```
post 'users/resume'
```

EDIT: all of this is occuring within a custom method

```
  def tagged
    @mcqs = MultipleChoiceQuestion.with_tag(params[:tag]).order("created_at DESC").published.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
    authorize @mcqs

    cookies.permanent[:saved_url] = request.original_url

 end
```

my problem is, i can't use the iVar that was proposed within a new custom method, so adding another method doesn't seem to  be working

Comment: Why not just create a current question association in you user model?

Comment: I've thought about a migration that does that, as in add an attribute to the users table called current_question, but i don't know how to make the button that would save an attribute with the saved / current URL

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would solve it.

#### 1. Add a current_question assocation to user:

```
class AddCurrentQuestionToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :current_question, foreign_key: { to_table: :questions }
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :current_question, class_name: 'Question'
end
```

#### 2. create a route that marks as question as the current question.

I'm assuming here that you have a `current_user` method.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
  patch :current
end

class QuestionsController
  # PATCH /questions/:id/current
  def current
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.update(current_question: @question)
      redirect_to @question, success: 'Current question updated.'
    else
      redirect_to @question, error: 'Could not update question.'
    end
  end
end
```

You can create a button to update this by:

```
<%= button_to 'Save question', question_current_path(@question), method: :patch %>
```

If you then want to link to the users current question you can do it by:

```
<%= link_to "Resume", current_user.current_question %>
```

The whole redirect step is completely redundant.

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out.. I have to use a local variable as the interface lives within a custom method.

Comment: Then just assign current_user.current_question to an ivar